# VB .NET error handling, pass error to caller

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

this is my very first project on vb.net and i am now struggling to migrate a vba working add in to a vb.net COM Add-in. I think i'm sort of getting the hang, but error handling has me stymied.

This is a test i've been using to understand the try-catch and how to pass exception to caller

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ActWkSh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ActRng As Excel.Range
    Dim ActCll As Excel.Range
    Dim sVar01 As String
    Dim iVar01 As Integer
    Dim sVar02 As String
    Dim iVar02 As Integer
    Dim objVar01 As Object

    ActWkSh = Me.Application.ActiveSheet
    ActRng = Me.Application.Selection
    ActCll = Me.Application.ActiveCell
    iVar01 = iVar02 = 1
    sVar01 = CStr(ActCll.Value)
    sVar02 = CStr(ActCll.Offset(1, 0).Value)
    Try
        objVar01 = GetValuesV(sVar01, sVar02)
        'DO SOMETHING HERE
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("ERROR: " + ex.Message)
        'LOG ERROR SOMEWHERE
    Finally
        MsgBox("DONE!")
    End Try

End Sub

Private Function GetValuesV(ByVal QryStr As Object, ByVal qryConn As String) As Object

    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim rs As Object

    Try
        cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        cnn.Open(qryConn)
        rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

        rs = cnn.Execute(QryStr)

        If rs.EOF = False Then
            GetValuesV = rs.GetRows
        Else
            Throw New System.Exception("Query Return Empty Set")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        rs.Close()
        cnn.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```

i'd like to have the error message up to test, but
            MsgBox("ERRORE: " + ex.Message)
pops out something unexpected (Object variable or With block variable not set)
What am i doing wrong here??
Thanks
D

Comment: What error were you expecting? What (wrong) behaviour are you trying to catch?

Comment: Turn on CLR exceptions - Debug -> Exceptions and check Common Language Runtime Exceptions (Thrown).  This should break at the error.

Comment: my idea is to get the full error message at the messagebox, so that it can be logged in a file (or worksheet). The error is that i do not get the customized error or any other error i trigger by syntactically wrong queries or typos in the connection string. I get the "object variable.." stuff.

Comment: @pm_2: no need to. i know for sure that the error is correctly caught. But the error message does not return the error i expect, but this "Object variable .." stuff.

Comment: i.e. whenever i intentionally use a wrong query statement, i expect the error message to be something in the line "ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax..." but i get "ERROR: Object variable ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you're doing a

```
Throw ex
```

Try using

```
Throw
```

instead.  This maintains the error stack, instead of generating a new one each time.

Based on your comments, I think the specific problem you're getting is in your `Finally` block.  You're trying to close the recordset and the connection, but if you got an error when you instantiated them, they will not exist; therefore, you get the `Object variable or with block` error.

(I would put the connection is a using statement anyway).

Comment: ok...makes perfect sense to me :) but what do you suggest? to leave the recordset and/or connection hanging there? My idea was to have a clean code that took charge of every object... i repeat, my first time toying with try-catch :) help me writing a nice piece of code :)

Comment: If your error is with generating the connection, then you don't have one.  If you put the code in a using statement then, I believe, if it errors it will dispose of the object for you.

Comment: ok, in my next test i'm going to check whether i can distinguish one error from the other. if this is the case i can dispose of the connection if it has already been established :) thanks a lot case closed ;)

Comment: nope, same error type for both.... i guess i'm going to drop the finally for sure :)